# defineProps() and ref() in Vue3 script setup stay empty

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-props

I am trying to use `defineProps` and `ref` in `<script setup>`, but props and refs are not visible in the template.

In this codeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/defineprops-and-ref-x54w51?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue, the prop "msg" and the value "name" stay empty.

The code for my component "HelloWorld.vue" looks like this:

```html
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>START</h1>
    <p>msg: "{{ msg }}"</p>
    <p>name: "{{ name }}"</p>
    <h1>END</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineProps, ref } from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
  msg: String,
});

const name = ref("This is my name");
</script>
```

I am calling this component like this:

```html
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" />
  <HelloWorld msg="Hello There!" />
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorldVue from "./components/HelloWorld.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld: HelloWorldVue,
  },
};
</script>
```

There is no error, but the result is missing "msg" and "name":
[image]

Am I doing anything wrone here, or is CodeSandbox broken?

Comment: I just tested it in Vue Playground. Seems it works - https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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

Comment: You seem right, thanks. Probably codeSandbox doesn't work correctly.
(If you came looking here fore the bounty that I just placed, I cannot reward a comment, but if you place your comment in an answer I can).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested it in Vue Playground. Seems it works - [link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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).